# Некорректно работает шифр Цезаря

Tags: python, шифрование

Написал шифр Цезаря, но почему то он работает не так. Когда вводишь ключ 3, все работает, когда ключ > 3 или < 3 он не шифрует. Выдает ошибку

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "d:\Универ\ИнфоБезопасность\Шифр Цезоря\Test.py", line 21, in <module>
>     cript += ALFA[index+key]
> IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

```
ALFA = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя,.:; "

key = int(input("Введите ключ: ")) #Ключ шифрования
lenALFA = len(ALFA) #Длина алфавита
cript = ""

#Открыти файла на чтение
file = open("D:\Универ\ИнфоБезопасность\Шифр Цезаря\Сообщение.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
word = file.read()
word = word.lower()
file.close()

lenWord = len(word) #Длина шифруемого текста

for i in range(lenWord):
    index = ALFA.find(word[i])
    if (index+key) > lenALFA:
        index -= lenALFA
        cript += ALFA[index+key]
    else:
        cript += ALFA[index+key]

#Запись зашифровоного сообщения
file = open("D:\Универ\ИнфоБезопасность\Шифр Цезаря\Зашифровоное сообщение.txt", "w",)
file.write(cript)
file.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `(index+key) > lenALFA` -> `(index+key) >= lenALFA`

Comment: так же работает с 4, 5 7 и многими другими

Comment: @Danis такая ерунда тогда получается с тему значениями, которые прежде ошибку выдавали :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Тогда почему у меня ошибка при ключе 5?

Comment: @Crazy_Soldierboy не знаю почему.  У меня при 5 нет ошибки. Зависит от исходного текста думаю, потому что в алгоритме ошибка

Comment: @Эникейщик Где ошибка?

Comment: ну где-то есть, раз не работает

Comment: зачем вот это? `if (index+key) > lenALFA:` в питоне нет остатка от деления? Если есть, то проще будет `index = (index+key) % lenALFA` и никаких if не потребуется

Comment: что сделает код, если в исходном тексте будет символ, которого нет в `ALFA`?

Comment: основная ошибка в том, что не учитывается регистр букв. Для компьютера буквы "Б" и "б" - это разные буквы. В случае когда попадается буква или символ, которых нет в **lenALFA**, то **ALFA.find(word[i])** возвращает -1 и возможно это "ломает" программу. Так как это никак не учитывается. Ну и плюс еще и исходный текст в UTF-8. Возможно это тоже добавляет проблем.

Comment: @newman На 10 строке есть функция .lower(). Она всю строку переводит в нижний регистр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут ошибка в мелочи, просто вы выходите за размер строки `ALFA` нужно всего-лишь добавить знак '=' в проверку длинны `if (index+key) > lenALFA:` полный исправленный код выглядит так:

```
ALFA = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя,.:; "

key = int(input('Введите ключ: ')) #Ключ шифрования
lenALFA = len(ALFA) #Длина алфавита
cript = ""

#Открыти файла на чтение
file = open("C:\\Сообщение.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
word = file.read()
word = word.lower()
file.close()

lenWord = len(word) #Длина шифруемого текста

for i in range(lenWord):
    index = ALFA.find(word[i])
    if (index+key) >= lenALFA:
        index -= lenALFA
        cript += ALFA[index+key]
    else:
        cript += ALFA[index+key]

#Запись зашифрованного сообщения
file = open("C:\\Зашифрованное сообщение.txt", "w",)
file.write(cript)
file.close()
```

так как знак `\` в строках в питоне нужен для экранирования и он же используется в путях Windows, нужно указывать их как `\\` что питон в строке воспринимает как просто `\`